# Sending emails using JIRA REST Client

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am working on JIRA REST client and we have a requirement to send emails.
I am wondering whether we can do that via JIRA REST Client.
Please let me know if anyone has idea on this.

Thanks in advance,
VVP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution I have used so that it may help some.

Since I have used JIRA Rest Client which was based on Java, I used Java Mail API to send mails.
First I retrieved data from JIRA Rest client and then parsed it and finally sent via Java Mail.

Let me know if you need any information on this. I can help.

Thanks,
VVP